# Jmeter is not parsing the token variable properly for Jira Token

Tags: jmeter, token, jira, csrf

I am getting this error trying to do a get request using JMETER

I stored the Atl_token in a parameter:

```
atl_token=BQK1-BRIY-PPQ6-LLVE|4619cd58d344d3723fc52273a2f08ab7153f99e0|
```

I added the lin behind it as it becomes

```
atl_token=BQK1-BRIY-PPQ6-LLVE|4619cd58d344d3723fc52273a2f08ab7153f99e0|lint
```

It keeps on saying that there is an illegal character. I have set my project to UTF-8 settings.

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 121: httB://MYSERVER.europe.intranet:8080/secure/WorkflowUIDispatcher.jspa?id=190484&action=1211&atl_token=BQK1-BRIY-PPQ6-LLVE|4619cd58d344d3723fc52273a2f08ab7153f99e0|lint&returnUrl=&decorator=dialog&inline=true&_=1419863300114
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:283)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1141)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1130)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:431)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:258)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

conclusion: I Need help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the module which accepts your request does not accept the  *atl_token* parameter in Encoded format.

You can try executing your HTTP request, with unchecked "Encode" check-box as highlighted in the image below.

[image: Jmeter]

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an option in Jira to disable token authentication.
If you put this option off before you test, it does not need authentication.